# foreach through a session variable

Tags: php, object, session, foreach

I would like iterate on each Object in my session variable.  'items' is of type item which is a class I've created to store book information. I have done a count($_SESSION['items']) which returns a 1 so i thought it should iterate at least once. But no luck.  Thanks

```
  foreach ($_SESSION['items'] as $item) {
      echo TEST;
      $sql = 'SELECT * FROM item WHERE Item_ID = '.$item->Get_Item_ID;
    var_dump($sql);
    }
```

Comment: Could you provide the result of var_dump($_SESSION['items']); ? Did you serialize your object before saving it into your session?

Comment: and if you do a `var_dump($_SESSION['items'])` your code looks fine to me.

Comment: Mayme you should try a vardump($_SESSION['items']);

Answer (score 3):

Why are you storing an object in a session variable?

http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php

Should be able to serialize and deserialize the object into a format that you can store within a cookie.

I think $_SESSION can only store strings and arrays.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to note that you should **never** perform a query in a nested loop like that. Rather, you should qualify your query like such....

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM item WHERE Item_ID IN (".implode(",", $_SESSION['items']).")";
```

Of course, you need to ensure that `$_SESSION['items']` is an array with at least one value, and that all values in `$_SESSION['items']` are in fact integers (or can pass for integers [such as string `"6"`]).

Comment: Also, make sure that the values that get stored in $_SESSION['items'] are validates as integers - otherwise, you're looking at SQL injection.

Answer (score 1):

I think you forgot to serialize/unserialize the object. It's not possible to just assign a object into a session variable. This is because the session gets written out into a file where your object stops to exist. Use [serialization](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop.serialization.php) to store an object into the Session.

Page 1:

```
 $user = new User();
 $_SESSION['user'] = serialize($user);
```

Page 2:

```
 $user = unserialize($_SESSION['user']);
```

Best wishes,
Fabian

Answer (score 0):

One final thing, ensure that the class definition for type 'item' is loaded before de-serializing your objects from the session. Otherwise you'll get errors when trying to access fields or methods on the object.